# Do constructors do the same thing as the '=' operator?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

1. When we didn't define any `=` operator, how does the compiler know
   to use constructors?
2. Isn't the constructor only called when defining a variable?

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    std::string name;
    Person(const char* fullName) : name(fullName) {}
};

int main()
{
    Person p1("Jibel Sadeghi"); // This is ok because we declared the constructor with a const char*
    /* When we didn't overload the '=' operator for 'const char*',
       how the next lines don't have any errors? */
    p1 = "Ben Sadeghi";
}
```

Comment: A trick is to implement all 5 and log what happens.

Comment: You have just told the compiler two ways to create a `Person` from other types, So it does that when needed. You can make the constructors `explicit` if you want to limit their use.

Comment: I didn't downvote. That was just a general advice.

Comment: @Jibel - You have no idea what people get called when giving a reason for their downvote. But it doesn't take long to realize you better not.

Comment: @Jibel Ok, it's not a good idea to bring that into your own question.

Comment: **ways to create**, We are not creating anything in lines `18` and `20` and we are just setting values @BoP

Comment: Some constructors will be implicitly available if you don't make any constructors of your own and this includes the [implicit copy/assignment constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

Comment: Next trick: Make a [mre].

Comment: Because you didn't define your constructor as `explicit`, it is called a _converting constructor_.

Comment: @heapunderrun This completely changes the meaning of the constructor for me, I'd thought a constructor just can be used when we declare the class

Comment: The compiler is smart If if needs an `X` and it has a `Y`, it'll go looking for ways to turn a `Y` into an `X`. The paths from `Y` to `X` it comes up with can be surprising sometimes.

Comment: I believe StackOverflow recommends downvoting **without** giving a reason.  (I don't have a link on hand.)  Otherwise, giving a reason often leads to an unconstructive discussion (or heated discussion) in the comments, and this isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't the constructor only called when defining a variable?

No.  A constructor is used when creating an object (instance of the class).

That object may be held in a variable, or an element of an array, or dynamically allocated, or (in the case you have here) a temporary object.

> When we didn't define any = operator, how does the compiler know to use constructors?

Your class has the default copy assignment operator, with signature

```
Person& Person::operator=(const Person& assign_from);
```

and default move assignment operator, with signature

```
Person& Person::operator=(Person&& move_assign_from);
```

When the compiler tries to compile

```
p1 = "Ben Sadeghi";
```

it sees that it needs `Person::operator=()`, looks at all the candidates (there's the default two, because you didn't provide any), and for each candidate it tries to convert the actual parameters to the types of the formal parameters.

For copy assignment, the formal parameter has type `const Person&`, the actual parameter has type `const char[12]`, and there's an implicit constructor able to perform the conversion.  So `Person::Person(const char*)` can be called, followed by `Person& Person::operator=(const Person&)`.

For move assignment, the formal parameter has type `Person&&`, the actual parameter has type `const char[12]`, and there's an implicit constructor able to perform the conversion.  So `Person::Person(const char*)` can be called, followed by `Person& Person::operator=(Person&&)`.

The `Person&&` argument is a better match for the temporary person than `const Person&`, so in the end the sequence `Person::Person(const char*)`  followed by `Person& Person::operator=(Person&&)` is chosen.

Comment: @fabian: Ah yeah, the defaulted move would have been defeated if any of the operator= were user-declared, or if copy constructor were user-declared, but here they aren't and so the default move assignment is not deleted.

Comment: There is a also an implicit conversion from `const char[12]` to `const char *`, in order to call `Person::Person(const char *)`

Comment: @Peter: Yes, that's a "free" conversion.